# Is there any way to login SSO using RestAssured or using any API calls?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, rest-assured

I've many automated scenarios and I need to perform SAML SSO login for each scenario execution.
Is there any way to perform this SSO login using any API calls or RestAssured instead of having it on browser so that I can save lot of execution time.

I initially thought of saving the cookies and reusing the same for further scenarios. I've developed the scripts for the same but was getting domain exceptions as it was getting navigated to microsoft page during login